# How to compress images before uploading them to Amazon s3 using django storages and django rest framework?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, django-storage

I'm trying to compress the images before uploading them to the amazon s3 server, but I couldn't do it, I used 'PIL', to do it, but it didn't work

This is the code I used with the library 'PIL':

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files import File

def compress(image):
    im = Image.open(image)
    im_io = BytesIO() 
    im.save(im_io,'PNG', quality=70) 
    new_image = File(im_io, name=image.name)
    return new_image

class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[validateFileSize])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_image = compress(self.file)
        self.file = new_image
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why don't you upload it and trigger lambda with s3 event and then compress it? Which part did not work? Could you provide snippet of code uploading to s3? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: @giaco thanks for answering, I have solved it

Comment: @AlexOnofre How did you end up solving it?

Comment: Alex, how did you solve it? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @NicolasRizzo I have published my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using the following code

```
def compress(image):
        im = Image.open(image)
        # create a BytesIO object
        im_io = BytesIO() 
        # save image to BytesIO object
        #im = im.resize([500,500])
        im = im.convert("RGB")
        im = im.save(im_io,'JPEG', quality=70) 
        # create a django-friendly Files object
        new_image = File(im_io, name=image.name)
        return new_image


    class Media(models.Model):
        file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[validateFileSize])

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.file:
                if self.file.size > (300 * 1024):
                    # call the compress function
                    new_image = compress(self.file)
                    # set self.image to new_image
                    self.file = new_image
                    # save
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```